Only take color cycle from a style
I hate everything about the style ggplot, but I do like the colors.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('ggplot')

This sets the colors from that style, and everything as well. How can I import only the color cycle from that style (for all lines, dots, ...), but import nothing else from that style?

The ggplot colors are defined here.  This Matplotlib doc page shows how to make the color cycle whatever you like.

@RuthC thanks for this - but I was looking for something less hacky and more elegant

To get the ggplot colors in Matplotlib without fully using its style, you can extract the color from ggplot and apply it to your plots:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Use ggplot style to get its color cycle
plt.style.use('ggplot')
colors = plt.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'].by_key()['color']

# Revert to the default style
plt.style.use('default')

# Apply ggplot colors to default style
plt.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'] = plt.cycler(color=colors)

plt.plot([1, 2, 3], [1, 4, 9], label="Line 1")
plt.plot([1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 1], label="Line 2")
plt.legend()
plt.show()

This code first switches to the 'ggplot' style to get its colors, after that reverts to the default style and applies the extracted colors.
Probably you can avoid running this code and just mock the colors:
colors = ['#E24A33', '#348ABD', '#988ED5', '#777777', '#FBC15E', '#8EBA42', '#FFB5B8']
plt.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'] = plt.cycler(color=colors)

UPD:
Here is a way how to apply this only for one chart, not setup globally.
colors = ['#E24A33', '#348ABD', '#988ED5', '#777777', '#FBC15E', '#8EBA42', '#FFB5B8']

# Create a context manager for the custom color cycle
with plt.rc_context({'axes.prop_cycle': plt.cycler(color=colors)}):
    # This plot will use the custom color cycle
    plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4], label='Line 1')
    plt.plot([4, 3, 2, 1], label='Line 2')
    plt.title('Plot with Custom Color Cycle')
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()



Temporarily switching styles would be a great use case for a context manager function: https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager

@shadowtalker indeed, see https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/customizing.html#temporary-styling

Thanks for the comments, you're right. I updated my answer above
